# offline, cross-tab communication (javascript-only)

Tags: javascript, tabs, instance, client-side, communication

Is it possible to find foreign instances of certain website? Ofc theese are independently opened tabs (not by window.open). I need to prevent user from opening 2 tabs, and send message to previously opened tab to inform that it's impossible to open 2 tabs. 2 Intependent tabs may break page offline storage and webSQL structure, so that I can't allow people to use 2 tabs. It's also semi-offline app so it needs to be client-side solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can communicate across tabs using localStorage. Every time you write a value, a "storage" event is fired on the window object on every tab (except the current one).

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Scroll down to "Tracking changes in the html5 storage area"

The event will include `event.key`, `event.newValue`, `event.oldValue`.

This only works in modern browsers.

Comment: oops I forgot to answer own question. Still thanks. Yes one disadvantage is that you have to add dust to every message as events won't fire when data will be the same. Anyone knows if YouTube uses it to open video links in existing tabs? I've tested it and works offline without flash but on the other hand I'm not so sure if yt would use walkaround like that

Answer (score 1):

In 2021, you can use service worker:

https://github.com/gyteng/service-worker-event

notice: service worker only works in **https** protocol

Answer (score 0):

localStorage can be used to track windows. You should take into account a situation when window crashes - it will leave the garbage in localStorage.
Accessing a common resource from several windows simultaneously may be done by mutex based on localStorage.

I've recently published the [interwindow communication library](https://github.com/slimjack/IWC) (all features are described in readme). It provides thread-safe data sharing, cross-window locks and event broadcasting. It also solves some IE issues.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast Channel is design for this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API

but the native api only support modern browsers.
there is a npm package support all old browsers as well
https://www.npmjs.com/package/broadcast-channel

Answer (score -1):

You don't have control over that. The user can do basically whatever he/she wants on the computer.

Comment: basically i could use system of expiring cookies to prevent doubled tabs however it doesnt allow me to send message in real-time across tabs. On Soundcloud only one tab at once can play music. any idea how did they achieve this? (it might be flash as i saw solution for this issue using flash but i dont want to use it)

Comment: The thing about JavaScript, everything is always wrong few years later.