# Webapp in 2 monitors

Tags: javascript, html, browser, multiscreen, multi-window

I am trying to find a way how to build a browser web app that runs in 2 monitors, like; 
i have a secondary monitor that i want to put there some *window*, i want it fullscreen, and automatically in the secondary, so no drags, while the main app should stay in the primary monitor, where is the browser... no way seems, nothing really works so the only way seems to be with some desktop app. 
I don't really care if the solution is browser dependent at this point, but still can't find a real solution.

Does a ny body tried something like this and can give me some ideas how to build it?

**EDIT**
... i need the second monitor to have some specific content, so not a clone of the primary... 
kind of... i'm playing some game in the first monitor and i see statistics on the second...

Comment: Can you describe a bit more detailed what exactly you are trying to achieve? How should those to windows work together?

Comment: should use the same information but show different views of that... and be in different monitors... Ex. main browser in the first monitor with some input and the second monitor should have maybe just a window with some kind of report of that input..

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible *yet*, but there is a [Presentation API](https://webscreens.github.io/presentation-api/) that is being discussed that would let you do exactly what you are looking for:

> This specification defines an API to enable web content to access external presentation-type displays and use them for presenting web content.

Unfortunately, it seems like there are no browser implementations yet.

Your only other option right now is to use 2 independent browser pages that communicate with each other somehow ([LocalStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824379/offline-cross-tab-communication-javascript-only), WebSockets etc.).

Comment: ..in fact i've tried this solution with 2 apps that are indipendent, and yes maybe the communication could be with localstorage... but i was thinking maybe there is some solution browser dipendent; so i consider that the only "smart" solution that i can think for the moment... still searching....