# Using same jquery ui slides on differents tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a single page app and came across a problem. How can I use same jquery ui slider on different tabs in the same page. For example if I change slider position on one tab it also shows on another tab.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have so far so that we don't have to start from the scratch..?

Answer (score 0):

Similiar question that has been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824379/offline-cross-tab-communication-javascript-only) Read hasenjs answer (the accepted one). He recomends using local storage, something that ought to work for your example too.