# ViewDidAppear-Like Method For JS/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say, there are two tabs with the same webpage open. **On one tab, I make some change in localStorage, then, when I go to the other tab, I'd like to see that change without having to reload the page.**

One way that I have thought to do this is by using a `setInterval` method, but for my application I don't really need to check for updates every 3-5 seconds so I don't feel this approach is ideal.

I am using React. **TLDR: Is there a good way to update data as soon as I open the tab of a previously-loaded webpage?**

---

Side Note For iOS Folks: On iOS, there is a `viewDidLoad` method (which from my understanding is similar to `componentDidMount`), and there is a `viewDidAppear` method (so I am basically, asking for the React/JS version of `viewDidAppear`?)

---

In regards to the possible duplicate question: To me, it seems fairly different, and this question is more React.js focused.

Comment: Does 'making a change' means you're just altering something in the client, or are you also doing some work in the server? if not, then it's impossible (given the current setup) to reflect the changes in the 2nd tab as it's not aware of the 1st tab

Comment: I am making a change to localStorage, which both webpages have access to

Comment: possible duplicate of [offline, cross-tab communication (javascript-only)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824379/offline-cross-tab-communication-javascript-only)

Comment: And also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12186061/95190 should be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the page visibility api or just window's focus event.  I recommend having a backup timer set to a minute or so... these events can be finicky.

There's nothing react specific about it other than [binding to global events](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here, have an imaginary choco chip cookie! I added an event listener for "visibilitychange" to my componentDidMount method

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and listen to localStorage on-change events:

```
 $(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
     console.log(e.originalEvent.key, e.originalEvent.newValue);
 });
```

This way, once a key in the local storage changes, you can reflect it in the 2nd tab.

If you're using react, then make sure you're rendering a component in your main component's render() function that makes use of you main component's `state` object. Once local storage has changed, update the `state` accordingly and react will take care of the rest.

Comment: React: I do currently update state when local storage changes, it works just on the current page though. I'll look into it, I might be doing it the wrong way.
JQuery: If I can't get React to work, I will add JQuery to the app (not currently using it), and try that out.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following lines of code to my main component.

In componentDidMount:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", this._callbackFunc, false);
```

In componentWillUnmount:

```
document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", this._callbackFunc, false);
```